# Passing external data into express send(res) function for server sent events

Tags: node.js, function, express, server-sent-events

I am only familiar with the concept of passing arguments to a function ('s parameters) yet.
I am not familiar with the apparently 'reverse' concept of the function send responding via the parameter (res).

My aim is to pass an array into the send function and the server to send events over the established stream.

It works well with code inside of the function send, but I do not know how to inject it from an external module.

Exporting send and requiring it in external modul throws: TypeError: send is not a function.
It seems to be an integral part of express rather than a function.
Therefore I was not able to experiment with argument.length loops etc.

Any help would be much appreciated.

```
app.get('/sse-stream', (_req, res, next) => {
    try {
        res.setHeader("Content-Type", "text/event-stream");
        send(res);
    } catch (err) {
        next(err); 
    }
});


function send(res) {

        // Inject setJson here from custom module
        // exporting send and requiring it in external modul throws: TypeError: send is not a function

        let setJson = JSON.stringify(input);
        res.write("data: " + `${setJson}\n\n`);
    }
```

Comment: Where does the `send` function come from?